# JPanel, List, JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Figured out the problem , Now I just don't know how to fix it .

The problem is when the user clicks Save Button , it saves all the textfields to the correct strings and to the Summary but it doesn't add the JPanel to the ArrayList of Panels .

```
saveEntryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String name = nametf.getText();
            String username = usernametf.getText();
            String password = passwordtf.getText();
            String description = descriptiontf.getText();
            String summary = "Name: " + name + "\n"
                    + "Username: " + username + "\n"
                    + "Password: " + password + "\n"
                    + "Description: " + description + "\n\n";
            JPanel entryPanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel entryLabel = new JLabel(summary);
            entryPanel.add(entryLabel);

            entries.add(entryPanel);
            entryFrame.dispose();

            mainMenu mmaa = new mainMenu();
            mmaa.menuFrame();


        }
    });
```

When debugging I saw that the ArrayList entries , was empty (size of 0) .

So that's why nothing is showing on the ViewFrame. Does anyone know how to make a List of JPanels ? Or any other container that is able to Add and Remove JPanels ?

Comment: So where exactly do I start looking and what am I looking for? Just a hint: If even begin too think you're posting too much, it highly likely you are. For faster help, learn to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As a beginner, you will learn alot by creating them. Instead of stressing over trying to debug hundreds of lines of code, you break your requirement down to simplest case. It makes it easier for _us_ to help you, and at the same time, you're able to focus _all_ your attention on that _one_ task, instead of trying to figure out why everything as a whole system...

Comment: ... doesn't produce the output you want.

Comment: I guess the only true problem is the viewEntryFrame()... It wont show the panels. Unless my addEntryFrame() is not doing its job when clicking the save button, I think I just don't know the correct way to show the multiple panels on the frame. Because I am using a ArrayList to store the panels in hope I can add/delete later on as the user feels necessary. But I can't get the Panels to show at all.

Comment: thank you for that MCVE link too.

Comment: @peeskillet I edited the post after finding what the problem is. If you think now it is more clear on what to do , if you could help i'd appreciate it.

Comment: @ericjets that's not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), an MCVE as you can read is a **Minimal Complete Verifiable Example**, i.e. A *full* code example which we can copy-paste and see the same output as you. That's a MCVE, as it is I don't see any ArrayList of Panels.

Comment: `dispose` releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its subcomponents, and all of its owned children. Maybe that's the cause *but I don't think so*. I think you have to post the whole code.

Comment: yeah, maybe you should call `entryFrame.dispose();` after `mmaa.menuFrame();` not before. As @giannischristofakis said

Comment: @ericjets just to specify: by *full* code I don't mean *ALL* your code, but a new file created by you, with the less code as possible you can have in it, and that we can copy-paste and it's still compilable.

Comment: whos wins???, if OPs joking then to close this question

Comment: @Frakcool Oh my bad , i understand what you mean now . But I did get the thing to work ! You were right to some extent , the problem I had was the arrayList was a member of the mainMenu class (which also has the menuFrame()) ... the problem was I was closing the first mainMenu (OBJECT 1) and opening a new mainMenu(OBJECT 2) each had its own ArrayList. Thank you for the help ! My future posts will be better organized as well haha